# How to add woocommerce product price filter widget to other page

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, filters

I had actually customise page ( which totally override by Attribute page template type),
And I want this page attche woocommerce widget "Filter product by price"

As I add shortcode: [woocommerce_product_filter_price] (https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-product-search/shortcodes/woocommerce_product_filter_price/) and it is not working
According to woocommerce doc, this is because woocommerce widget only show in category, shop pages

Does any solution I could retrieve woocommerce widget "Filter product by price" to my customise page ?

Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

you can require the price filter template from where ever you want

go inside your woocommerce template folder and copy

`plugins/woocommerce/templates/content-widget-price-filter.php`

to your `yourtheme/woocommerce/content-widget-price-filter.php`

and then require it in the your file